# sqldataAdapter in Csharp in easier way?

Tags: database, sqlite, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-mvc-3, model-view-controller

I am new to Model view Controller so i wanna know what's the exact meaning of data Adapter. I used to create procedure but after that in my controller i use object of sql command and then by using adapter i fetch data's of tables that exists in database.

```
public void ExecuteSelectQueryWithDataTable(String procedureName, SqlParameter[] sqlParameter, out DataTable dataTable)
    {
        dataTable = new DataTable();
        Random Rnd = new Random();
        try
        {
            using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
            {
                using (SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand("", sqlConnection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataAdapter sqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(sqlCommand))
                    {
                        sqlCommand.CommandText = procedureName;
                        sqlCommand.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                        sqlCommand.Parameters.AddRange(sqlParameter);
                        sqlDataAdapter.SelectCommand = sqlCommand;
                        sqlDataAdapter.Fill(dataTable);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

SQLDataAdaptor is one ado.net class that fill datatable by database table or result set of stored procedure.

I suggest to connect to DB by entity framework instead of legacy development.

BR